# store different templated class in the same container

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following class:

```
template<unsigned int offsetX, unsigned int offsetY>
class myClass {
//several int and floats that are computed with offsetX and offsetY
//and other stuff
}
```

Its size is the same regardless of what are the templated parameters.
Can I store instances of myClass<1,1> and myClass<0,0> etc, in the same container? I understand it's not possible when the templated thing is a class, but in this case the layout of the class is always the same

edit : I know I could send offsetX and offsetY to the constructor of the class and have no template but in this case they are known at compile-time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define base class for your template where all of these common ints and floats will be placed.

Use your derived template only to compute base fields. Then you can insert  your template instances to container defined with base class. This is called object slicing. In general it is not a a good thing...

Better would be to drop template class and to define template function which will do what is already done by your template c-tor.

```
template <int x, int y> inline MyClass compute()
{…}
```

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot, since the types are different. You can use a common base class and store [smart pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) to it, or store [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/any.html).

```
class MyBase { .... };

template<unsigned int offsetX, unsigned int offsetY>
class myClass : public MyBase{ .... };
```

then

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyBase>> v;

v.push_back(std::unique_ptr<MyBase>(new myClass<1,1>()));
v.push_back(std::unique_ptr<MyBase>(new myClass<0,0>()));
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. The types `myClass<1, 1>` and `myClass<0, 0>` are unrelated.